# codeigniter file upload using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

hello i have this function using AJAX. i need to retrieve the file's name size type and i will have to save it to my database..

here is my code.

```
 function UploadImage() {
 var data = new FormData($('#fileName'));
 Jquery.each($('#fileName')[0].files, function(i,file) {
    data.append(i,file);
 }
    $.ajax({
       type: 'post',
       data: data,
       url: 'controller/function',
       cache: false,
       ContentType: false,
       ProcessData: false,
       success: function(data) {
          alert(data);
       }
 }
```

when i will retrieve the data coming from the ajax request through my controller, i cant get the data of the files using _$Files[] it has error saying undefined index.

Comment: you have to post your whole code ie php code also.

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you

```
function UploadImage() 
{
  var data = new FormData(document.getElementById("fileName"));//remember fileName is your form id.
  //You dont need this
   /*Jquery.each($('#fileName')[0].files, function(i,file) {
     data.append(i,file);
   }*/
   //you don't need to modify the data. data already contains whole form information.
   $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      data: data,
      url: 'controller/function',//better use full path instead of relative path
      cache: false,
      ContentType: false,
      ProcessData: false,
      success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: hi sir. i did this but when i var_dump the result it returns null.